# Ruby update on mountain lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling to get Ruby updated on my macbook pro. I am currently running 1.8.6, and need to upgrade to at least 1.8.7 to install rails. I have rvm, but every time I try to install a new version of ruby I get the following error:

```
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/telenardo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/make.log
```

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

When I open the make.log file, I get the following message:

```
[2012-07-29 21:39:20] make 
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o main.o -c main.c
In file included from ./include/ruby.h:32,
             from main.c:13:
./include/ruby/ruby.h:70:20: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:1343,
             from ./include/ruby.h:32,
             from main.c:13:
./include/ruby/intern.h:27:22: error: varargs.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Could anyone shed some light on what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not much help, but I would recommend going to Ruby 1.9.3. You're already updating, so why not get the new features and such...

Comment: Indeed, that would be preferable. In this particular example I was attempting with 1.9.2 - I've been trying just about everything to get this to work.

Comment: have you run this? `$ rvm get head && rvm reload`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution here (creating a symlink to gcc-4.2) fix the problem?

http://www.zlu.me/blog/2012/02/21/install-native-ruby-gem-in-mountain-lion-preview/